# Illustrator Rename Selected Layer or Sublayer

Tags: script, adobe-illustrator, illustrator-cs6

I would like to Options Dialog Box pop up when I press 'F2'.
What could I do for it, please?
[image]

Comment: I haven't checked, but have you tried editing the keyboard shortcuts to see if that option was available that way?

Comment: I can't find it there.